# Getting the data of one column from another column in Excel

Tags: sql, excel, database, excel-formula

I am having the following data in Excel containing thousands of students records with their GPAs.

As you can see in the image, there are multiple records for the same student, each of witch having his/her GPA in a single semester.

I want to calculate the final GPA of all of students, the final GPA is the GPA the student got in his/her final semester. So how can I collect and take the highest (semester) value of one student and to take its corresponding GPA value?

Is it possible to do this in Excel and how?
and if anyone can lead me how to do it in Python or SQL?

Thanks
[The image of the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KKdo.png)

**Update** I figured it out by using the *(Group by)* feature, that is working in the *(Power Query Editor)* in Excel.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: I am having Microsoft office home and students 2016, Excel version (2112).

Comment: What does a negative student # mean? You selected 3 positive and one negative of a number. Are they really the same?

Comment: @bugdrown, the negative sign does not refer to anything, the four highlighted rows are for the same person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood your aim to be find all records for a given student ID, and then find the maximum value of the GPAs.

I would recommend doing this using a pivot table.

1. Highlight cells containing your data
2. Go to Insert > Pivot Tables; Click OK on the pop up dialog
3. In the right hand panel that shows up, select Student Number & GPA to be shown.
4. Ensure Student Number is in the Rows box. If it is not, drag it to the Rows box.
5. Ensure GPA is in the Values box. Right click > Field settings. A pop up with "Summarize By" should show up. In the list, select Max.

Let me know if this helps! Can add screenshots if needed.

Comment: Great, that helps a a little. Just want to ensure that I want the max (Semester)  and the value of GPA of that semester. 
and can I convert it to normal worksheet afterword? 
Thanks a lot